# How do I get a UTC Timestamp from Calendar?

Tags: java, localization, calendar, timezone, timestamp

In Java when I use `Calendar.getInstance();` I get a `Calendar` object for the current Timezone. But `java.sql.Timestamp` is usually stored in UTC Time and not in local time. So how can I get the UTC Time from a Calendar instance?

```
    DateFormat df = DateFormat.getTimeInstance();
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    Timestamp time = new Timestamp(cal.getTimeInMillis());

    // Prints local time
    System.out.println(df.format(new Date(time.getTime())));

    // Printe local time, but I want UTT Time
    System.out.println("timestamp: " + time);
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

When you call `Calendar.getTime()`, that will give you a value which doesn't have a related time zone - or you could think of it as being in UTC - for the *instant* that the calendar represents. So if it was (say) 9am in the calendar's time zone, it could be 5pm UTC.

Now `java.util.Date` (and I'd imagine `Timestamp`) will be *formatted* in the system default time zone when you call `toString()` (whether implicitly or explicitly) - but don't let that fool you into thinking that the time zone is part of the data within the object itself.

You need to be very clear about *exactly* what you're trying to achieve - and then you'll probably find that [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sf.net) lets you express that in code more clearly than the built-in libraries do.

Comment: I actually get a `Calendar` instance from an API, and then I have to get the UTC Timestamp from that. I like Joda Time, but I can't use it here.

Comment: @Jonas: Okay, in that case you just need to use `getTime()` - that will give you a UTC timestamp.

Answer (score 12):

Your code is already doing exactly what you want. `Timestamp` (as well as `Date`) does not have timezone information and should always contain a GMT timestamp (which ist what `Calendar.getTimeInMillis()` returns).

The reson why you see local time printed is that the `DateFormat` factory methods as well as `Timestamp.toString()` implicitly use the system timezone.

Comment: Ok, is it any way to make `DateFormat` display it in GMT Time?

Comment: @Jonas: DateFormat has a setTimeZone() method

Answer (score 5):

## tl;dr

```
Instant.now()
```

## Avoid legacy date-time classes

You are using troublesome old date-time classes now supplanted by the java.time classes. No need to be using `DateFormat`, `Calendar`, or `Timestamp`.

If you must interopt with a [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html) from old code not yet updated to java.time, convert using new methods added to the old classes. Extract an obsolete `java.util.Date`, and convert to `Instant`.

```
Instant instant = myCal.getTime().toInstant() ;
```

## Using java.time

Get the current moment as an `Instant`. The [`Instant`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) class represents a moment on the timeline in [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) with a resolution of [nanoseconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nanosecond) (up to nine (9) digits of a decimal fraction).

```
Instant instant = Instant.now() ;
```

> 2017-02-17T03:29:15.725Z

### Database

With JDBC 4.2 and later, you can directly exchange a `Instant` object with your database. So no need for the obsolete `java.sql.Timestamp`.

```
myPreparedStatement.setObject( … , instant ) ;
```

And retrieval:

```
Instant instant = myResultSet.getObject( … , Instant.class ) ;
```

### Count from epoch

Apparently you want a number of milliseconds since the [epoch reference date](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epoch_(reference_date)) of `1970-01-01T00:00:00Z`. You can extract that number from an `Instant`. But beware of data loss, as a `Instant` has a resolution of nanoseconds which you will be truncating to milliseconds.

```
long millis = instant.toEpochMilli() ;
```

> 1487302155725

---

## About java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8) and [**SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9) and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - The [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above) for Android specifically.
  - See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [ThreeTen-Extra](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Answer (score 3):

Following snippet should satisfy your requirements:

```
df.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
```

Comment: I've just formatted your answer , and didn't downvote.