# Get TimeStamp with system time function in android?

Tags: java, android, timestamp, system

I am building an android application where I need the TimeStamp but not of local system machine.

What I have done to get TimeStamp used below function.

```
System.currentTimeMillis()
```

The problem I was facing in that suppose if the system time is set wrong I will be getting wrong Time in that condition.

Is there any lib. from where I can get current timestamp.

Comment: You should try to get timestamp from some network service

Answer (score 0):

May be this can be helpful to you:

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance(); 
int mseconds = c.get(Calendar.MILLISECOND);
```

Comment: This will also use the system time.

Comment: @Divya this will also use system time that I don't want as clear mention in my question

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative you can use

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
Timestamp time = new Timestamp(cal.getTimeInMillis());
```

(See this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4377279/how-do-i-get-a-utc-timestamp-from-calendar) for example).

But I don't know what happens when the system time is wrong (can't test it now).

Comment: This will also use the system time That I don't want

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want the system time, you have to get the timestamp from an external resource. This could be your own internet server, a ntp server, you can get a timestamp from gps, ...
Have a look at this related question / answer: 
[Network Time from NTP Server](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14720918/1771537)

Comment: I don't want to use any network call to get timestamp

Comment: @sofquestion9 Where else could the timestamp come from? You don't want it from the system (device), then it must come from an external resource which is (without any special hardware) internet or gps.